# Find maven dependency "com.sun.javadoc"

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

My osgi bundle in servicemix need `com.sun.javadoc` for start. 
I find dependency in maven repository but without success : the dependency in this link [[here]](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.sun.javadoc)

I try :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javadoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>javadoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.7</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```

... without success.

So, I look for maven dependency for `com.sun.javadoc` with `version : 1.7.0`

thx

Comment: What does `${java.home}` points to? Does `${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar` exists?

Comment: yes it's my JAVA_HOME (echo $JAVA_HOME : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle)

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"? What does `ls -l ${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar` print?

Comment: It does not work. for ls -l ${java.home}/../lib/ : amd64, ant-javafx.jar, ct.sym, dt.jar, ir.idl, javafx-mx.jar,  jconsole.jar,  jexec, missioncontrol,  orb.idl, packager.jar, sa-jdi.jar, tools.jar, visualvm => this is all

Comment: Ok, but what does "It does not work" mean? Does the JAR appears in the dependency tree? What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is I don't find the right maven dependency for com.sun.javadoc.

Comment: I resolve it, see answer

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem :
In my pom.xml I make :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>My_JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

and in `<Embed-Dependency>` section I take the artifactId for this dependency, in my case it's "tools"

new `mvn install` and now in servicemix not stack for com.sun.javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Just add tools.jar to your library folder.
example if you are using IntelliJ IDEA:
file->project structure->Libraries->(+) new project library->
Choose tools from your JDK path ->
your problem must be resolved